# Why is Reinforce so small?

Tags: nanoha

At the end, of *Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha A's* and during *Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha StrikerS*, Reinforce is quite small.

[image: Reinforce is bigger!]

However, in the above image she is shown to be just as big as Vita. The image above doesn't look like fan art and it's obviously set a few years after StrikerS as Tina is wearing the Enforces' uniform and has longer hair.

I am wondering why Reinforce was so small. Is it because she was still a new born that's yet to grow? If so, can Agito eventually grow up to be normal size since both Rien and Agito are Unison Devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was explained in the StrikerS soundstages  that she can turn into human size, but that cost her more magical power, which makes it not practical for combat. And Agito can do the same.

Source

http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Reinforce_Zwei